# Disabling button click but allowing MouseHover?

Tags: vb.net, button, mousehover, isenabled

I have a button that checks a log file, and if the text doesn't match a specific string the button is disabled. I did this using:

```
button.enabled = False
```

This disables the control as intended - but I want to keep a MouseHover event enabled.

Is it possible to disable clicking?

**Edit:**

**Changing text on hover:**

```
Private Sub AIR_Button_MouseHover(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AIR_Button.MouseHover
    Dim AIRfileReader As String
    AIRfileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("X:\Logs\Air\AirConnectedUser.txt")
    AIR_Button.Text = AIR_Button.Text.Replace("Air", AIRfileReader)
End Sub

Private Sub AIR_Button_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AIR_Button.MouseLeave
    Dim AIRfileReader As String
    AIRfileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("X:\Logs\Air\AirConnectedUser.txt")
    AIR_Button.Text = AIR_Button.Text.Replace(AIRfileReader, "Air")
End Sub
```

**Disabling the button:**

```
Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("X:\Logs\ConnectionState.txt")
    If fileReader.Contains("AIR Account logged in") Then
        AIR_Button.BackColor = Color.IndianRed
        AIR_Button.Enabled = False 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more code? Only the variable `button` isn't much to begin with.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not firm with AIR, but in this case I see a possibility: Do not disable the button, but make the button click conditional. In your button click Function (or Sub), check for a global bool that is set by this filereader. Instead of `AIR_Button.Enabled = False` you'd set this global bool to false.